# Issues with form after adding a new field

Tags: php

I have added a new field to my form and is giving me the below error message;

> [Fri Jun 17 09:59:22.955088 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3992457:tid
> 140534207178496] [client 86.29.27.155:50430] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP
> Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null in
> /var/www/vhosts/asdfasdf.com/sdfasdf.com/clients/review/add-review.php:19,
> referer: https://sdfsadfssadf.com/clients/review/add-review.php?id=9
> [Fri Jun 17 09:59:22.955127 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3992457:tid
> 140534207178496] [client 86.29.27.155:50430] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack
> trace:, referer:
> https://dfghdfghdfghfghdfghdfgh.com/clients/review/add-review.php?id=9
> [Fri Jun 17 09:59:22.955135 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3992457:tid
> 140534207178496] [client 86.29.27.155:50430] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0
> /var/www/vhosts/dfghfdsghfd.com/fdgndfgdhgf.com/clients/review/add-review.php(19):
> PDOStatement->execute(Array), referer:
> https://kadsfasdfasdfc.com/clients/review/add-review.php?id=9 [Fri Jun
> 17 09:59:22.955142 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3992457:tid
> 140534207178496] [client 86.29.27.155:50430] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1
> {main}, referer:
> https://asfasdf.com/clients/review/add-review.php?id=9 [Fri Jun 17
> 09:59:22.955148 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3992457:tid 140534207178496]
> [client 86.29.27.155:50430] mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in
> /var/www/vhosts/23423423423.com/324234234.com/clients/review/add-review.php
> on line 19, referer:
> https://sdgdstrs.com/clients/review/add-review.php?id=9

I have named the field as Duration and added the entry into the database with the same name.

Code;

```
<?php
include '../../main.php';
check_loggedin($pdo);
$msg    =   null;
$date = new DateTime();
$totay_date = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
// Check if the contact id exists, for example update.php?id=1 will get the contact with the id of 1
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Get the contact from the contacts table
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
    $contact = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(isset($_POST['date']) == null || isset($_POST['engagement']) == null || isset($_POST['reminder_date']) == null || isset($_POST['care_update']) == null || isset($_POST['review_note']) == null || isset($_POST['duration']) == null){
        $msg    =   '';
    }else{
        $id = isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO care_plan_review VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $result = $stmt->execute([$id, $_GET['id'], $_POST['reminder_date'], $_POST['engagement'], $_POST['care_update'], $_POST['review_note'], $_POST['note'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['amount'], $_POST['duration']]);
        $msg    =   "New Care Plan Entry Added!";
    }

    if (!$contact) {
        exit('Contact doesn\'t exist with that ID!');
    }
} else {
    exit('No ID specified!');
}

?>
```

Code for field

> ```
>                         <div class="form-row">
>                             <div class="form-group col-md-12">
>                                 <label >Duration*</label>
>                                 <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" class="form-control"></textarea>
>                             </div>
> ```

I have double checked the code and matches the rest of the statement and can remove the added on field and information and starts working again.

Comment: when your $id value is null , then the problem happen cause a primary key could'nt be null

Comment: Awsome @Romylussone - thanks for that. Changed         $id = isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['id'] : NULL; to         $id = isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['id'] : AUTO; and worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

here is your first mistake you start with input but the end is textarea
fix it and the code will work correctly